# get Unlimited Phone Number table view Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

there is a table view to get user phone numbers exactly like ios contact ui . **the question it is how user can add unlimited phone numbers in textfield** . now user can add just three number in textfield .

```
let indexpath0 = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)
let cell0 = tvInsert.cellForRow(at: indexpath0) as? InsertTableCell1

let indexpath1 = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 1)
let cell1 = tvInsert.cellForRow(at: indexpath1) as? InsertTableCell1

let indexpath2 = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 1)
let cell2 = tvInsert.cellForRow(at: indexpath2) as? InsertTableCell1

if contactModel.phoneNumbers.count == 0 {
    cell0?.txtPhoneNumber.text = " "
    mutableContact.phoneNumbers.removeAll()
} else if contactModel.phoneNumbers.count == 1{
    mutableContact.phoneNumbers = [CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile, value:CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: cell0?.txtPhoneNumber.text ?? ""))]
} else if contactModel.phoneNumbers.count == 2 {
    mutableContact.phoneNumbers = [CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile, value:CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: cell0!.txtPhoneNumber.text!)), CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile, value:CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: cell1!.txtPhoneNumber.text!))]
} else if contactModel.phoneNumbers.count == 3{
    mutableContact.phoneNumbers = [CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile, value:CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: cell0!.txtPhoneNumber.text!)), CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile, value:CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: cell1!.txtPhoneNumber.text!)), CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile, value:CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: cell2!.txtPhoneNumber.text!))]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var table1Text: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var table2Text: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var table1: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var table2: UITableView!

    var table1Data = ["a"]
    var table2Data = ["1"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func addData(sender: AnyObject) {

        //add your data into tables array from textField
        table1Data.append(table1Text.text)
        table2Data.append(table2Text.text)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            //reload your tableView
            self.table1.reloadData()
            self.table2.reloadData()
        })


        table1Text.resignFirstResponder()
        table2Text.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    //delegate methods
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == table1 {
            return table1Data.count
        }else if tableView == table2 {
            return table2Data.count
        }
        return Int()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView == table1 {
            let cell = table1.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

            let row = indexPath.row
            cell.textLabel?.text = table1Data[row]

            return cell
        }else if tableView == table2 {

            let cell = table2.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

            let row = indexPath.row
            cell.textLabel?.text = table2Data[row]

            return cell
        }

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on what you are trying to implement but if you are trying to let the user add phone numbers and not have a limit on the maximum number of fields, you can implement a dynamic tableView.

You would have an array of phone numbers and your tableView would have those phone numbers listed + one clickable row that would insert a new phone number.

So, essentially the number of rows in your tableView would be equal to phoneNumbersArray.length (number of phone numbers in array + clickable new phone number row). Everytime the new phone number row is tapped, you would add an entry to your phone numbers array and insert a row in your table (or reload the table).